# Setting a variable's value according to the existence of two or more variables

Tags: php

How can we set a variable's value according to the existence of one or more variables?
This works but I want to know if PHP has a "shorthand" version for this:

```
if (isset($a)) { $x=$a; } elseif (isset($b)) { $x=$b; }
```

In case you want the bigger picture, I need to give $x the value of $_REQUEST['a'] or $_GET['a'], whichever one exists each time.

**EDIT**: ternary operators will do the trick for 2 variables. Could the functionality expand for more than 2? Example

```
if (isset($a)) { $x=$a; } elseif (isset($b)) { $x=$b; } else { $x=$c; }
```

Comment: Use ternory operator in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may stack [***ternary***](http://php.net/ternary) operators:

```
<?php
$x = isset($a) ? $a : (isset($b) ? $b : null);
?>
```

Also, it might be extended to:

```
<?php
$x = isset($a) ? $a : (isset($b) ? $b : (isset($c) ? $c : null));
?>
```

**NOTE:** You need braces to avoid non-obvious execution.

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's
>   behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single
>   statement is non-obvious.

I recommend, to do not complicate such expressions too much. It might affect code readability.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operator:

```
$x = isset($a) ? $a : $b;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. However I changed my question to cover a larger range of variables, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I think ternary operators quickly becomes unreadable if misused. So let me suggest an alternative way of thinking:

```
$x=$c;  // default
if (isset($b)) $x=$b;
if (isset($a)) $x=$a;
```

Or:

```
function first_set($array,$default=null){
    foreach($array as $e) if isset($e) return $e;
    return $default;
}

$x=first_set(array($a,$b),$c);
```

Comment: +1 for the top one. It is good when you may handle code growth in height, no in width.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this:

```
$x = ($a) ?: $b; // if you are using 5.3+

$x = ($a) ? $a : $b; // if >PHP5.3
```

Comment: This will trigger : `Notice: Undefined variable: a` (in both versions)

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=isset($a)?$a:(isset($b)?$b:'default value');
```

You can nest as many conditions as you want.\

```
$x=isset($a)?$a:(isset($b)?$b:(isset($c)?$c:'other ternary condition'));
```